# Define a class that extends Function

Tags: javascript, class, extending-classes

I'm trying to create a class that extends `Function`.

```
var MyClass = class MyClass extends Function {
  constructor(func, /*some other things*/) {
    //this is not defined in extended classes for some reason
    var newThis = func;
    //assign other stuff to newThis
    return newThis;
  }

  //methods

}
```

At first I thought this would work but an `instanceof` check revealed that the object created was just a regular function without any of my methods or properties. So then I realised that I need to use the `super` keyword to `construct` a `Function`.

```
var newThis = super(func.toString().split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(','),
                    func.toString().split('{')[1].split('}')[0])
```

This works but it doesn't comply with the content security policy (something like that) which means that it won't work in chrome apps.

Comment: Why do you want to extend `Function`?

Comment: Because I want to create a function-like class that has some extra methods and properties

Comment: haha. Adding methods to a function. That does sound a little silly

Comment: Based on the weird `split` chain, it looks like OP is trying to create a `Function` constructor that takes a function string as a single argument.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33832646/extending-built-in-natives-in-es6-with-babel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% what you're trying to do, but in order to correctly extend a class in ES6 you must called `super()` before you do anything.

```
class Foo extends Function {

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.x = 'foo';
  }

}

let test= new Foo();
console.log(test.x); // 'foo'
```

You can try it out on the babel REPL [here](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=class%20Foo%20extends%20Function%20%7B%0A%20%20%0A%20%20constructor()%7B%0A%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20this.x%20%3D%20'foo'%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20test%3D%20new%20Foo()%3B%0Aconsole.log(test.x)%3B)

Comment: I'm missing something here. `test` is a function that is defined how, and will do what when you call it?

Comment: I've never actually extended Function so I don't actually know. I can tell you that Function is a subclass of Object, and has a bunch of methods and properties on it's prototype for more details. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)