# How can I extend the Array class in Babel?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I'd like to define a shortcut method for inspecting the end of a stack.

The following works in Firefox:

```
const Stack = class extends Array {
  last() {
    return this[this.length - 1];
  }
}
```

However, after compiling this with Babel, it doesn't work:

```
var Stack = function (_Array) {
  _inherits(Stack, _Array);

  function Stack() {
    _classCallCheck(this, Stack);

    return _possibleConstructorReturn(this, Object.getPrototypeOf(Stack).apply(this, arguments));
  }

  _createClass(Stack, [{
    key: 'last',
    value: function last() {
      return this[this.length - 1];
    }
  }]);

  return Stack;
}(Array);


console.log(Stack.prototype.last); // works
console.log((new Stack()).last); // doesn't work
Array.prototype.last = Stack.prototype.last;
console.log((new Stack()).last); // works
```

For some reason, I can add functions to the new prototype, but they won't be available to instances of that prototype unless they're inserted directly into the Array prototype (which is obviously bad practice due to potential side effects).

---

**Update**: There might be several ways to get around this (including Proxy objects, or extending the prototype manually instead of using `extends`), but since my `Stack` doesn't really *need* most of the Array methods, I'm now simply using a wrapper.

```
  const Stack = class {
    constructor(...x) {
      this.arr = [...x];
    }
    pop() {
      return this.arr.pop();
    }
    push(...x) {
      return this.arr.push(...x);
    }
    top() {
      return this.arr[this.arr.length - 1];
    }
    size() {
      return this.arr.length;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Likely duplicate: [Extending built-in natives in ES6 with Babel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33832646/extending-built-in-natives-in-es6-with-babel)

Comment: Turns out that NodeJS was a red herring here - the latest version supports it just fine. Babel's output doesn't work in the browser or node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about Babel support but node.js started supporting (partially) `Array` subclassing since version 4.3.2 and implemented full subclassing support in version 6.8.1 (http://node.green/#Array-is-subclassable). So if you're using node 6 `Array` subclassing should work.

If Babel is failing you you can always do it the "classical" way:

```
// Code tested and works in 6.3.1:
function Stack = () {};
Stack.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);
Stack.prototype.last = function () {
    return this[this.length - 1];
}

var s = new Stack();
```

Comment: Isn't the problem with the "classical" way is that array methods that return new arrays (like `.slice()`) don't return your derived type?

Comment: @jfriend00: that's not a problem with prototypal inheritance or class inheritance. After all, the ES6 spec makes classes merely syntax sugar on top of prototypes - they're the same thing. The problem is support for subclassing. ES6 specifies that Array can be subclassed. Most browsers don't support this yet but node.js started supporting from 4.3.2. I've used it in one of my projects and it works exactly like you'd expect arrays to work - down to the `x[y]` syntax working properly on your subclassed array

Comment: Thanks, the problem was indeed Babel (after updating NodeJS to be able to run the un-transpiled file at all). I'm now using a wrapper class and passing through the push()/pop() methods explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

You might use this plug-in (Babel 6):
https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-builtin-extend

The plugin describes some limitations for IE <= 10, however.

**Update**: But this plugin is not even needed for Babel 7.

Comment: Hey, could you elaborate this update a bit? I'm using Babel 7 and I have problem extending Map class. How should I set it up?

Comment: I don't remember the specifics of this, but I'd file a new question with the error you're getting (and if it is during compilation or when you try to use the resulting compiled code in a specific environment) and any plugins you tried.

Comment: Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66423488/babel-doesnt-work-with-ie11-on-built-in-class-map-extending

Comment: upgrading to Babel 7 was the only working option for me

Answer (score 0):

this was the solution for me. now myArray objects are treated as myArray instead of Array class type

```
class myArray extends Array
{
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
    
        this.constructor = myArray;
        this.__proto__ = myArray.prototype;
    };
}
```