# Babel doesn't work with IE11 on built in class Map extending

Tags: javascript, typescript, internet-explorer, babeljs, internet-explorer-11

I have some legacy code, a class `ExtraMap` that extends built-in `Map` class.

```
export class ExtraMap<K, V> extends Map<K, V> {
    getOr(key: K, or: OrFunctionType = defaultOrFunction): V {
        const value = this.get(key);
        return !!value ? value : or(key);
    }
}
```

In IE11 I am getting this error: `Object doesn't support property or method 'getOr'`

Babel version is 7, but whatever I tried it just doesn't seem to work out.

I have tried `plugin-transform-classes` and `plugin-proposal-class-properties`, even `babel-plugin-transform-builtin-extend`, but nothing helped.

Here is whole `.babelrc` config:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-classes",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"
    ]
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the **lodash** in your project? If yes, try to install the [babel-plugin-lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-lodash). See whether it makes any difference.

Comment: Yes I am, I'll try that.

Comment: I tried it, it didn't help.

Comment: Did you try to set the target to IE 11? `{
  "targets": {
    "ie": "11"
  }
}` If not, I suggest you make a test with it.