# Extend Array with custom method

Tags: javascript

I want to extend an `Array` so as to add custom methods to it.

Here is my attempt at doing so:

```js
class DataArray extends Array {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  add(item) {
    this.push(item);
  }
}

const dataArray = new DataArray();
dataArray.add(1);
```

But gives the error `Uncaught TypeError: dataArray.add is not a function`

The error happens only when I use Babel or Typescript to compile the code.

Comment: I tried it in google chrome console. It works fine.

Comment: You can directly add like this, if you want to keep it global right?
Array.prototype.add = Array.prototype.push

Comment: @ShankarShastri Yes, I just realised I'm getting the error only when using Babel to compile it (or typescript). You can see this from running the snippet

Comment: @ShankarShastri I don't want to add it to the Array prototype, it runs the risk of someone overriding it and I like to override a method too

Comment: *"The error happens only when I use Babel or Typescript to compile the code."* At least Babel doesn't support extending built-in classes, since that wasn't possible in ES5 either (i.e. you cannot really replicate it). See [Extending built-in natives in ES6 with Babel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33832646/218196)

Comment: @FelixKling, so unless I compile to ES6, I cannot use this feature?

Comment: You cannot use `class ... extends` to extend built-in classes, yes.

Comment: This is currently possible with Babel 7

Answer (score 0):

Seems like its not supporting shorthand method definitions, try arrow function assignment instead:

```js
class DataArray extends Array {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  add = (item) => {
    this.push(item);
  }
}

const dataArray = new DataArray();
dataArray.add(1);
console.log(dataArray);
```

Your version is still fine though, it could be the interpreter version in this REPL, If you try your own example say in jsbin, it works fine

Comment: Currently, this is just invalid syntax in a `class`.

Comment: That's not ES6. Public class fields are a proposal. `foo() { ... }` is the correct way to define a method in a class.

Comment: nope, not invalid syntax
http://jsbin.com/yujurivofo/edit?js,console,output

Comment: @Ignacio _Your_ code is invalid, not the one from the OP.

Comment: Added snippet example to demostrate

Comment: You demonstrated it using Babel, not using ECMAScript.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that extending built-in classes is not officially supported by Babel. That's the actual issue, not how they define the method.

Comment: @FelixKling I see what you're saying, I thought using babel wasn't an issue in this case

Answer (score -1):

If you want to improve built-in javascript Array, you can use prototypes. (In this example adding method remove to javascript built-in Array type to remove the given elements from an Array):

```
  Array.prototype.remove = function () {
      var array   = this;
      for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
          for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
              if (arguments[i] === array[j]) {
                  array.splice(j, 1);
              }
          }
      }
      return array;
  };

  // Usage: [1, 2, 3].remove([1, 2]);
```

Comment: But this isn’t the question here.