# Typescript: class extending Array, can't assign method

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm working with Typescript and Vue, but I hope that my framework doesn't matter.

I'm trying to extend Array like that:

```
class AudioArray extends Array<[number, number]> {
    constructor(size: number) {
        super(size);
    }

    static fromArray(array: Array<number>): AudioArray {
        return array.map((v, i) => [i, v]) as AudioArray;
    }

    addNumber(num: number): AudioArray {
        return this.map((x: [number, number]) => [x[0], x[1] + num]) as AudioArray;
    }
}

export default AudioArray;
```

and I'm importing it into my component:

```
<script lang="ts">
import AudioArray from '@/utils/audioarray'
```

```
someFunction() {
    const normalArray = [0,1,2,3,4];

    const audioValues = AudioArray.fromArray(normalArray);
    const audioValues2 = audioValues.addNumber(2);
}
```

My static function `fromArray` works very well, but I have such a message:

**"TypeError: audioValues.addNumber is not a function"**

I've logged `AudioArray` and `audioValues` to console and here's the result

[image: devTools]

Comment: Consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33832646/extending-built-in-natives-in-es6-with-babel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is how you create instances of AudioArray:

```
static fromArray(array: Array<number>): AudioArray {
    return array.map((v, i) => [i, v]) as AudioArray;
}
```

The fact that you use `as` cast to silence the compiler does not make the result of `array.map` an instance of `AudioArray` (that is, does not set prototype chain). You need to use a proper constructor to do that.

```
class AudioArray extends Array<[number, number]> {
    constructor(size: number) {
         super(size);
    }

    static fromArray(array: Array<number>): AudioArray {
        const ret = new AudioArray(0);
        ret.push(...array.map((v, i) => AudioArray.toRecord(i, v)));
        return ret;
    }

    static toRecord(a1: number, a2: number): [number, number] { 
        return [a1, a2];
    }

    addNumber(num: number): AudioArray {
        const ret = new AudioArray(0);
        ret.push(...this.map((x: [number, number]) => AudioArray.toRecord(x[0], x[1] + num));
        return ret;
    }
}
```

More generally, extending Array to add methods is questionable design, think if you can achieve your goal using composition.