# Why Typscript Array.map preserves runtime type for class extending Array

Tags: typescript

When answering this question: [Typescript: class extending Array, can't assign method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60892542/typescript-class-extending-array-cant-assign-method)
where the original author extended Array class to add some methods, I arrived to following class:

```
class AudioArray extends Array<[number, number]> {

    static fromArray(array: Array<number>): AudioArray {
        const ret = new AudioArray(0);
        ret.push(...array.map((v, i) => AudioArray.toRecord(i, v)));
        return ret;
    }

    static toRecord(a1: number, a2: number): [number, number] { 
        return [a1, a2];
    }

    addNumberToEach(num: number): AudioArray {
        const ret = new AudioArray();
        ret.push(...this.map((x: [number, number]) => AudioArray.toRecord(x[0], x[1] + num)));
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Surprisingly, following method, which uses this.map and casts the result to `AudioArray` seems to preserve runtime type

```
addNumberToEachInPlace(num: number): AudioArray {
   return this.map((x: [number, number]) => [x[0], x[1] + num]) as AudioArray;
}
```

Example:

```
const audioArrayA = AudioArray.fromArray([1, 2, 3]);
const audioArrayB = audioArrayA
    .addNumberToEachInPlace(1)
    .addNumberToEachInPlace(2);

console.log(audioArrayB);
```

**My Question**

Why the runtime type is preserved, given the documentation of [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> The `map()` method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

Comment: Why do you think the `.map` changes the type of the array?

Comment: @VLAZ If it constructs a new Array, I expected it to use `new Array()` form the base class, not from extended class (Sorry if I don't have the correct mindset, I am new to JS / Typescript)

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the issue. Are you saying that `.map()` *should* produce a base array yet it doesn't and produces the same array that was mapped or the opposite `.map()` *should* produce the current type of array but it produces the base array instead?

Comment: @VLAZ I expected it to produce base array type, but in fact it preserves the type - it produces the extended type (proven by the fact chained `addNumberToEachInPlace` works)

Comment: OK, got it now. Sorry for being slow.

Comment: @Caramiriel I am OK with accepting it as the correct answer. Can you copy your comment to the answers section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current ECMAScript specification, where Javascript is based on, states that the array must preserve it's type. So it's more of a Javascript requirement than a TypeScript implementation issue.

Below a copy of the specification for reference, note step 4 of `Array.prototype.map`:

**Array.prototype.map**

```
1. Let O be ? ToObject(this value).
2. Let len be ? LengthOfArrayLike(O).
3. If IsCallable(callbackfn) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
4. Let A be ? ArraySpeciesCreate(O, len).
5. Let k be 0.
6. Repeat, while k < len
   a. Let Pk be ! ToString(k).
   b. Let kPresent be ? HasProperty(O, Pk).
   c. If kPresent is true, then
        i. Let kValue be ? Get(O, Pk).
       ii. Let mappedValue be ? Call(callbackfn, thisArg, « kValue, k, O »).
      iii. Perform ? CreateDataPropertyOrThrow(A, Pk, mappedValue).
   d. Set k to k + 1.
7. Return A.
```

And zooming in, ArraySpeciesCreate indeed specifies that it must create the same type of array, steps 5 and further:

**ArraySpeciesCreate**

```
 1. Assert: ! IsNonNegativeInteger(length) is true.
 2. If length is -0, set length to +0.
 3. Let isArray be ? IsArray(originalArray).
 4. If isArray is false, return ? ArrayCreate(length).
 5. Let C be ? Get(originalArray, "constructor").
 6. If IsConstructor(C) is true, then
    a. Let thisRealm be the current Realm Record.
    b. Let realmC be ? GetFunctionRealm(C).
    c. If thisRealm and realmC are not the same Realm Record, then
       i. If SameValue(C, realmC.[[Intrinsics]].[[%Array%]]) is true, set C to undefined.
 7. If Type(C) is Object, then
    a. Set C to ? Get(C, @@species).
    b. If C is null, set C to undefined.
 8. If C is undefined, return ? ArrayCreate(length).
 9. If IsConstructor(C) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
10. Return ? Construct(C, « length »).
```

*Sources:*

- https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.map
- https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-arrayspeciescreate

Answer (score 1):

The documentation on MDN is *correct*. But not at all explicit in its explanation how different types of arrays are handled.

When the description says "*The `map()` method creates a new array*" that is *true* - it does create a new array, however it will base its type on the original:

```js
class MyArray extends Array {
  //simple chainable method
  isMyArray() {
    console.log("yes, this is MyArray with content: " + this.join(","));
    return this;
  }
}

const arr = new MyArray();
arr.push(1, 2, 3);
arr.isMyArray();

const result = arr
  .map(x => x + 1)
  .isMyArray();
```

This isn't explicitly explained on MDN but the [specs do make it clear](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.map):

> **22.1.3.18 Array.prototype.map ( *callbackfn* [ , *thisArg* ] )**
> When the **map** method is called with one or two arguments, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let *O* be ? ToObject(**this** value).
> 2. Let *len* be ? LengthOfArrayLike(*O*).
> 3. If IsCallable(*callbackfn*) is **false**, throw a **TypeError** exception.
> 4. Let *A* be ? ArraySpeciesCreate(*O*, *len*).
> 5. Let *k* be 0.
> 6. Repeat, while *k* < *len*
>   a. Let *Pk* be ! ToString(*k*).
>   b. Let *kPresent* be ? HasProperty(*O*, *Pk*).
>   c. If *kPresent* is **true**, then
>     i. Let *kValue* be ? Get(*O*, *Pk*).
>     ii. Let *mappedValue* be ? Call(*callbackfn*, *thisArg*, « *kValue*, *k*, *O* »).
>     iii. Perform ? CreateDataPropertyOrThrow(*A*, *Pk*, *mappedValue*).
>   d. Set *k* to *k* + 1.
> 7. Return *A*.

Step 4. is the relevant detail. I'll just quote the description without the steps for brevity:

> **9.4.2.3 ArraySpeciesCreate ( originalArray, length )**
>
> The abstract operation ArraySpeciesCreate with arguments *originalArray* and *length* is used to specify the creation of a new Array object using a constructor function that is derived from *originalArray*.

So, `.map()` will create a new array using the constructor of the one that was called on. This is very important, since otherwise custom arrays would not be of much use if they were transformed to a base array after any mapping operation. This is true for any of the methods that generate a new array. For example:

```js
class MyArray extends Array {
  //simple chainable method
  isMyArray() {
    console.log("yes, this is MyArray with content: " + this.join(","));
    return this;
  }
}

const arr = new MyArray();
arr.push(1);
arr.push(2);
arr.push(3);
arr.isMyArray();

const result = arr
  .map(x => x + 1)
  .isMyArray()
  .map(x => x * 2)
  .isMyArray()
  .flatMap(x => [x, x])
  .isMyArray()
  .concat([3, 2, 1])
  .isMyArray()
  .filter(x => x % 2 == 1)
  .isMyArray()
```

Without preserving the type of the array, you'd have to re-wrap the base array in your own one at any step in case you want to do something different